# Superset and subset the same by definition?

Tags: logic

Let's say I got arbitrary sets with the properties $A$ and $B$

Are the following statements equivalent?

- Every set with the property $A$ is a subset of a set with property $B$
- Every set with property $B$ is a superset of a set with property $A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For example, let the only A-set be $\{1\}$, and let both of $\{1,2\}$ and $\{2\}$ be B-sets.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Let there be two disjoint sets $U,V$ that have property $B$ and let sets have property $A$ if and only if they are subsets of $U$ and are not empty.

Then the first bullet is a true statement, but the second is not: $V$ is not a superset of a set with property $A$.