# Can superset and subset be used interchangeably?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it true that $A \subset B \iff B \supset A$? I have been using both interchangeably in order to save time when Latexing some notes, but [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2010501/superset-and-subset-the-same-by-definition) question gave me some pause.

Comment: They are the same thing

Comment: Like @JoshuaTilley said, they can be used interchangeably. It's a matter of style. The question you linked is unrelated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are the same thing. Just like $x<y$ and $y>x$ are the same.

The post you're referring to is asking a different question. It's asking about families of sets, and whether "Every set from family $A$ has some superset in family $B$" means that "Every set from family $B$ has some subset in family $A$".